# Sending email to Hotmail or Outlook in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to send email in asp.net, it works find and send email to GMAIL and YAHOO mails but not working on HOTMAIL or OUTLOOK account.
Here is code...

```
Dim pass As String = RandomPassword.Generate(8, 10)
ta.insertuser(txtuser.Text, pass, txtfname.Text, txtlname.Text, txtemail.Text, droprole.SelectedValue, radiostatus.SelectedValue, DateTime.Now())

Dim senderma As New MailAddress("client@karacode.ir", "karacode")
Dim recipientma As New MailAddress(txtemail.Text)
Dim mm As New MailMessage(senderma, recipientma) With {
    .Subject = "Account Details",
    .SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    .Body = "<div style='font-family: tahoma; font-size: 10pt; padding: 1em; direction:rtl; text-align: justify; line-height: 2;'>" & "Dear User" & " " & txtfname.Text & " " & txtlname.Text & "<br />" & "You're most welcom to KARACODE" & "<br /><br />" & "Your account information<br /><br />" & "Username : <br />" & txtuser.Text & "<br /><br />" & "Password : <br />" & pass & "</div>",
    .BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    .IsBodyHtml = True
}
Dim cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential With {
    .UserName = "client@karacode.ir",
    .Password = "Client164418054545"
}
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient With {
    .Host = "webmail.karacode.ir",
    .EnableSsl = False,
    .UseDefaultCredentials = True,
    .Credentials = cred,
    .Port = 25
}
smtp.Send(mm)
```

Please gives the tips to solve the problem.
MANY THANKS

Comment: Maybe it is not a code problem, but a SPAM one... is it possible?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No way this code works with Google. Google dropped unencrypted communications over port 25 years ago. *Many* years ago. It *requires* TLS now. Most likely this code doesn't work with *any* public provider anymore because they *all* require TLS.

Comment: Plus, there are no "HOTMAIL or OUTLOOK" account. They are the same thing. Furthermore, Google and/or Outlook won't allow you to send anything unless you enable this for your account. There are a lot of duplicate questions about this